# Laravel: при POST запросе сервер возвращает 500

Tags: laravel

Я столкнулся с проблемой, при AJAX (POST) запросе к серверу, он возвращает мне 500 ошибку.

Я добавил Meta:

```html
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token()}}">
```

Сам Javascript код и кнопка при нажатии на которую происходит запрос:

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-XSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            console.log('loaded');
        });
        
        function reload() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#result').html(data)
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('Ошибка')
                }
            });
        }
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="reload()">
        Перезагрузить
</button>
```

Контроллеры:

```js
 public function get()
 {
  return view('pages.main');
 }

 
 public function post()
 {
  return 'hello';
 }
```

Роуты:

```js
Route::get('/', [
 'before' => 'csrf',
 'as'     => 'main_get',
 'uses'   => 'Main@get'
]);
Route::post('/', [
 'before' => 'csrf',
 'as'     => 'main_post',
 'uses'   => 'Main@post'
]);
```

Логи:

```html
[2017-03-20 15:10:46] local.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException' with message 'The payload is invalid.' in W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter.php:180
Stack trace:
#0 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter.php(123): Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter->getJsonPayload('zUITv5lAe1oJy1o...')
#1 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php(139): Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter->decrypt('zUITv5lAe1oJy1o...')
#2 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php(121): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->getTokenFromRequest(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php(63): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->tokensMatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#5 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#8 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#11 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#14 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#17 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(561): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#20 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(520): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(498): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(174): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#29 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#35 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(149): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#38 W:\domains\training.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 W:\domains\training.com\public\index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 {main}
```

Comment: Дубль https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641943/laravel-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-500-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83

Comment: Да, это дубль, этот вопрос тоже создал я, но добавлять комментарии и редактировать предыдущий вопрос я не могу, поэтому мне пришлось создать новый

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Автор вопроса не указал версию Laravel. Однако, есть мнение считать, что он использует версию 5.3 или 5.4, но синатксис команд очень похож на 4.*
Это в корне не верно. 
Хорошо бы если автор указал версию Laravel, т.к. они сильно отличаются.

Если я прав, то используйте актуальный синтакис
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing

Сейчас вместо before используются middleware. Однако, при отправке запросов через web вам не надо заботится о проверке csrf, т.к. он будет автоматически проверен.

**The VerifyCsrfToken middleware, which is included in the web middleware group, will automatically verify that the token in the request input matches the token stored in the session**

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-introduction

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй передать токен здесь:

```
function reload() {
    let token = $("#token").val();

    $.ajax({
    url: '/',
    data: token,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#result').html(data)
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log('Ошибка')
    }
    });
}
```

https://webzone.kz/publication/laravel-routing